# Accessing file information for all users, C#

Tags: c#

I'm writing a short C# program that will iterate over each user on a given Windows system, check in their local app data folder for a specific directory, and operating on it if it exists.

I'm looking for a good way to resolve the absolute file path to each users' local app data folder. I can use `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` but that will only work for the user that is currently running the program.

I know I can cobble together a few different utilities  and make a couple assumptions about where a user's local data is usually stored to make it work for 99% of the time (determine a list of [all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318611/how-to-get-all-user-account-names-in-xp-vist-7-for-32-or-64-bit-and-any-os), go through each one and find/guess where their app data is, etc.), but I was hoping there was a more elegant solution?

Comment: Uh ... isn't the user profile directory standard amongst Windows installations? For Vista/7/8, isn't it always `C:\Users\<Username>`? Therefore, isn't the AppData folder always at `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData`? Couldn't you just iterate through the folders in the `C:\Users` directory, then? You'd just have to check if this was XP or not (NT version = 5.1) and change "Users" to "Documents and Settings", if you want to support XP, too.

Comment: That's what I figured, but could a user still have re-located their appdata folder to some non-standard location?

Comment: Also, note that your program will not only need to run as Administrator, but the user account udner which the process is running will need explicit read/write access on the ACL of the other user's appdata folder, which is NOT granted by default (you will need to add it explicitly). This is *especially* true on Windows 8 since they changed how Administrator accounts worked (the security is tighter).

Comment: No, as far as I know, it's not possible to relocate a user's profile directory or the appdata folder without significant work on their end. You could always have a fallback, and include a command line option in your program where you can specify the relative appdata path if they decide to move it. The reason this isn't "elegant" is because you aren't supposed to be messing around with other user's appdata folders. A lot of people will tell you this is a bad idea.

Comment: Perhaps if you explain what, exactly, it is you're trying to do, someone can suggest a better way of going about it?

Comment: Oh, well the program this utility will support sometimes has an issue after an update where the files in the local app data are still "cached" if you will to the old version, which causes all kinds of problems. So this needs to go find their app data folder, find the specific directory, remove it and replace it with the updated file located under the Program Files, and it needs to operate over all user accounts... which I foresee getting a might bit hairy when trying to delete another users data...

Comment: You are going to have a hell of a time trying to write this, bypassing all of the security that Windows has in place to prevent malicious apps from doing exactly this (looking at and modifying other user's profiles), not to mention testing it and bugfixing it once you've written it. Honestly, the program should be clearing its cache when it updates, it sounds like the fault of whoever wrote this original program. Get them to fix their stuff instead. :)

Comment: @SpikeX It is possible to relocate user profiles, though it's as good as impossible after Windows is installed. It is however something that can be specified in an unattended installation. Not to mention that the path names may be localized for non-English versions of Windows (I don't believe this particular one is, but in general that could be true).

I think the only "clean" way to do this would be to have the app impersonate all other users and perform the operation in each user's own security context.